# Resaltar fila recién insertada en jsGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery

Utilizando jsGrid quiero resaltar la fila recién insertada para una mejor visualización del usuario:

En el callback onItemInserted intento hacer lo mismo que en rowClick (al hacer click se resalta la fila).

```
    onItemInserted: function (args) {
        var $row = this.rowByItem(args.item);
        $("#jsGrid_medidasImpDig").jsGrid("loadData");

        var selRow = $("tr.selrow");
        selRow.removeClass("selrow"); // quita el resaltado a la fila actualmente resaltada
        $row.addClass("selrow"); // resalta la nueva fila
    }

    rowClick: function (args) {
        var $row = this.rowByItem(args.item);
        var selRow = $("tr.selrow");
        selRow.removeClass("selrow");
        $row.addClass("selrow");
    }
```

loadData en onItemInserted es porque cuando se crea una nueva fila, siempre se va al final de la lista, al hacer loadData se hace un efecto como que la lista no se mueve y el nuevo registro aparece insertado en el lugar que le corresponde. Cuando el nuevo registro aparece insertado es cuando quiero resaltarlo, como se ve en la imagen. En el caso de la imagen, se acaba de insertar el 15 X 20.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: loadData no afecta al rendimiento porque no son más de 500 registros, la inserción de la fila es inmediata. Si alguien conoce otra forma mejor de hacerlo le agradecería que lo comente.

Gracias por la colaboración

Comment: Intenta desmarcar primero la que pudiera estar marcada y, solo entonces, asignar la clase a la nueva fila.

Comment: Eso hago con estas 3 líneas:

var selRow = $("tr.selrow");
selRow.removeClass("selrow");
$row.addClass("selrow");

Comment: También he intentado con $row.addClass("selrow"); sólo, ya que realmente no hay ninguna fila resaltada previamente.